# What do scissors mean in a diagram?

Tags: diagram

I'm trying to wire an immobilizer bypass for a vehicle remote start, but I have never seen scissors in a diagram before. Anyone know what this means?
[image: Scissors]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that you need to cut the existing wire as part of installation.

Comment: Thats what I thought it might mean, but it didn't make any sense. The remote starter is not currently wired to the chip sensor. It looks like its telling me to wire the immobilizer bypass to the chip sensor, then immediately un-wire it.

Comment: I see what you mean now, the #1 sensor wire needs to be cut so that the immobilizer bypass is in series. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The wire needs to be cut so that the function (starter operation probably) is now controlled by the immobiliser as well as the ignition switch.

When I fitted these, part of the installation was to make that connection in a difficult to see or find location so it was not easy to find or by-pass.

Comment: I think I get it now. The #1 sensor wire needs to be cut so that the immobilizer bypass is in series?